# MongoDB - Java Driver performance

Tags: java, mongodb, performance, mlab, database

This is my environments.

Java - 1.7 by Oracle

mongod v2.4.5 (in Mongolab)

I found difference in performance of the two MongoDB driver(2.9.3 vs 2.11.2)

When I run same code using each driver, 2.11.2 slower than 2.9.3.

```
   for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
        BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject(
                "currentTime",
                new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
        );
        coll.insert(doc);
    }

    DBCursor cursor = coll.find();
    try{
        while(cursor.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
```

The above code is to put 1000 document to MongoDB.

In driver 2.9.3, it takes 1~2 sec.
but in 2.11.2, it takes more than 1 minute.

Does anyone know anything about this problem?

Comment: inserting 1000 documents shouldn't take 1minute even with the new default write concern. Small documents like this takes microseconds on my laptop. One small tip in case you're not aware, a bulk insert will probably be faster. You can insert a list of documents. This means that there is only one round trip for your 1000 docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default Write concern has changed from NORMAL to SAFE for Java driver since V 2.10.0
[See here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/drivers-write-concern/)

This means that in the older driver version insert operations by default return as soon as a message is written to socket.

In the newer driver version on the other hand, operations by default must be acknowledged by the server before returning, which is much slower.